# Remember item order in Menu bar between reboots

Tags: menu-bar, macos

macOS Sierra added ability to rearrange items in the Menu bar, however after rebooting computer they reset to their previous order.

[image]

I'm not using Bartender or any Menu bar controlling apps.

How can I make icon order permanent?

Comment: It may require updates for those apps to be compatible.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without a 3rd-party solution.  They store the order of the icons and restore that order upon reboot.

Comment: a link 3rd party app to do that would be a great answer to my question.

Comment: This is most likely a macOS Sierra bug, see iStat Menu's known issues: https://bjango.com/help/istatmenus5/knownissues/

Comment: O boy you have like 500 items in the top bar :/

Comment: @romaninsh Why not use Bartender then?